# css make responsive oval block

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to make a css blocks for numbers shown in image below. My idea / goal is to make one responsive block so if there will be one number it will be round, if two then like second. I have been tried to make border-radius: 50% so the first block I succeed to do second was not like in image with border-radius: 50%

So my question is it possible to make such result with one class block or for each button (left | right) I need to write special class for each block ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Fixed Height Solution

For this you will need a "fixed" height (otherwise, you'll need to calculate this with jquery).

What you'll need to do is something like this;

```css
html,body{background:#222;}
div {
  margin:10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
  color:blue;
}
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:-10px;
  width:100%;
  border-top:3px solid tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>123</div>
```

Note: The border-radius should be set to half the overall height for this.

I've also included a min-width to ensure it is always at least a circle.

---

## JQuery Solution For non-fixed heights

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').each(function(index) {
    var height = $(this).height();
    $(this).css("border-radius", height + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #222;
}
div {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:top;
  color: blue;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>123</div>

<div>Not a set height,
  <br/>either :)</div>
```

Comment: You'd better use jQuery's `.height()` method — like: `.height() / 2` — as`$(this).css("height")` doesn't return the computed value of height (in this particular case it returns `60px` because of two lines of text having a `line-height` of `30px`).

Comment: @HashemQolami: Thanks for the tip :) (I'm no Jquery pro).

Answer (score 6):

For ellipse use 100%:

```
border-radius: 100%;
```

For stadium use big value in px:

```
border-radius: 9999px;
```

#### Example

```css
.round{
  display: inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.ellipse,.stadium{
  width: 80px;
}

.stadium{
  border-radius: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="round circle"></div>
<div class="round ellipse"></div>
<div class="round stadium"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 border-radius:9999px;
 background:red;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 line-height:3em;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:16px;
  }
```

```html
<div>2</div>
 <div>28</div>
```